# How to pass an argument to function in Controller from antoher Controller in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I work on a project in Laravel 8. In one controller I receive some data by $request, and I do something with them. After that, when data is ok I want to pass then to the next Controller to do with them another work.

I'm doing it like that:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function validation(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
    
        if (!is_numeric($data['from']) || !is_numeric($data['to']) || !is_numeric($data['attempts'])) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Form fields with number in theirs name must be a number']);
        } elseif ($data['from'] <= 0 || $data['from'] >= ($data['to'] - 2)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Field with the lowest number must be grater than 0 and at least 2 smaller than field with the highest number']);
        } elseif ($data['to'] <= 2 || $data['to'] <= ($data['from'] + 2)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Field with the highest number must be grater than 2 and at least 2 bigger than field with the lowest number']);
        } elseif ($data['attempts'] <= 0) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Field with number of attempts must be grater than 0']);
        } else {
    
            $user = new User;
    
            $user->playerName = $data['name'];
    
            $user->save();
    
            $data['id'] = $user->id;
    
            return redirect()->action(
                [GameController::class, 'index'],
                $data
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the other Controller:

```
class GameController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request, $data): View
    {
        dd($data);

        return view('game');
    }
}
```

Problem is that I get error message:

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Game\GameController::index(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

Is there a way to give $data from one to another controller?

Maybe there is a way to add some data to the $request in one controller and pass it to the other controller this way?

Comment: your controller method is specifying it is taking a route parameter, `$data`, but this information is inputs not a route parameter

Comment: Ok. So witch method can I use in this case?

Comment: you would have to get this data from the request the same way you are doing it currently in the `validation` method and remove that parameter from your controller method

Comment: It's work but there is one problem. After saving my user to database, i adding one parameter id to this data. But this parameter will not be in the request. How can I add it to the request?

Comment: This smells a bit funky to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I didn't add whole code, only necessary. This is a simple game, guess the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first controller you should do something this:

```
return redirect(route('routeToSecondController', [*your data*]));
```

Will be a better if it will POST.
You shouldnt add more than one argument in second Controller. All data will be kept in $request->all().

Do not validate data the way you do it. I recommend you
do it in request classes with rules (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation)
or use Assert library for validation (https://github.com/beberlei/assert).
I hope I helped you

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will try validate other way, as you show me. But with the redirection I have another problem, I have error: Array to string conversion.

Comment: OK. I handle this error. Thanks, everything if working fine.